# Derivatives of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

For a symmetric matrix we have:

[image]

That is comparable to what we do, to what you learn in the first analysis course with one variable. And that was already clear to me, also in linear algebra.

But the reason behind it is the following:

[image: when we derive a scalar.]

Can anyone explain the intution behind the second equation? It's a definition in the book I currently read.

Comment: Marlon, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write this out in coordinates, then
$$x'Ax = \sum\limits_{j,k = 1}^n x_jA_{j,k}x_k.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x'Ax = \sum\limits_{j,k = 1}^n \delta_{i,j}A_{j,k}x_k + \sum\limits_{j,k = 1}^n x_jA_{j,k}\delta_{i,k} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n A_{i,k}x_k + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n x_jA_{j,i} = (Ax)_i + (A'x)_i.$$

Comment: Klaus, please do not answer very low-quality questions.